# Apache Flink - Tweet Vectorization for SVM

Tags: scala, vectorization, svm, apache-flink, libsvm

i am currently working on a hate speech filter using Apache Flink's FlinkML programmed in Scala.

I have a huge .csv training dataset containing rows like:

```
id,count,hate_speech,offensive_language,neither,class,tweet

326,3,0,1,2,2,"""@complex_uk: Ashley Young has tried to deny that bird s*** landed in his mouth ---&gt; http:**** https:****"" hahaha"
```

My Problem is, that Flink doesnt include a Vectorizer to transform the Tweets to a LibSVM File readable for the SVM.fit() function.

Do you guys have any idea how i could transform the data above using the "class"-column as a label and the "tweet"-column as the feature vector to train my SVM?

I really appreciate any help. Searching for hours.

Comment: As far as I know libSVM doesn't define on how you build your vector. So you have to come up with your own vector representation (e.g. TF/IDF or Doc2Vec)

Comment: @TobiSH Hey first of all thanks for your answer. Is there any TF/IDF or Doc2Vector Implementation i could integrate in my flink application through maven?

Comment: You can use Smile library: https://haifengl.github.io/smile/ https://haifengl.github.io/smile/api/java/smile/nlp/relevance/TFIDF.html

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 thank you :) i will try this one later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is not (yet) a Flink problem. Flink is a stream processing engine (batch processing is also possible but stream processing is the unique selling point for flink). You can define stateful computations at an unbounded stream. **How** you do that is up to you. One of the first problems you need to solve is: How do I represent my text as a vector which can be used as an input for a SVM clustering. TF/IDF might be a good starting point. Implementations can be found all over the place: [HaifenGL/SMLE](http://haifengl.github.io/smile/nlp.html) or [Deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/datavec-overview) are some popular examples.

Please also keep in mind that if you deal with very short documents (twitter tweets if I got you right). You should consider to keep as much tokens (words) as possible - this will increase the size of your vocabulary - which will increase the dimensions of your vectors (if you stick with some kind of bag-of-words-like model) - which will force you to get more training data.

After solving all this ML related problems you can think of how do I integrate this into flink.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer :)
yes now that i looked deeper into it i found my way.

I am using HaifenGL/SMLE for calculating the tfidf values. 

The only bad thing is, that i have to keep my vocab next to me with all terms to match the calculated value for one word of a tweet with the right index for this word.

Only know this from sklearn were you just throw everything in you TFIDFVectorizer.

Thanks again for your answer. you showed me that i am on the right way :)